# Building whole sheet programmatically with Python SDK

Tags: python-2.7, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to build a whole sheet from scratch, and stay efficient while doing it.
For that purpose, I am trying to rely on bulk operations.

I can build a massive list of rows and add them easily using `add_rows()`.

However, I need some rows to be children of other rows, and neither `row.indent` nor `row.parent_id` seem possible to set on new rows (since the fresh rows don't have an id yet).

I could possibly: create the parent row > `add_rows()` > `get_sheet()` > find the row id in sheet > create the child row > `add_rows()` but I'm losing the benefits of bulk operations.

Is there any way at all so set child/parent relationships in python before ever communicating with the smartsheet server?

[Edit] Alternatively, a way to export an excel file via the SDK (or other) would also work, as I'm able to create my table with xlsxwrite and upload it manually to smartsheet at the moment. (Which is not an option, as we're trying to generate dozens of sheets, multiple times a day, got to automate it.)

Thanks

Comment: I notice in the UI, there is a function to upload a .xlsx file to smartsheet. Is there a way to do this via the SDK? python xlsxwriter lets me generate a hierarchy on the fly, which imports pretty well into smartsheet (only issue is it doesn't seem to recognize the contact names, but I may be able to address that later on).

Comment: Edited original question to include the additional question.

Comment: I notice that with release 1.3.3, the option to upload an xlsx file has been added. I'll take a look at this. Does anyone know if this would allow to create project sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a sheet with hierarchy in a single call. All rows in a single POST or PUT must have the same location specifier.

You can either:

(1) Add all rows as a flat list, then indent each contiguous group of child rows. Repeat down the hierarchy.

(2) Add top level rows, then add each contiguous group of indented rows

Comment: I am looking into solution 1 at the moment, will update with what I end up using once I figure it out. Thanks

Comment: None of these solutions seem to work great for our case.
I'm able to put everything out as a single flat hierarchy, but then I still need to go and set parent ids one by one. (very few of our rows share the same parent, though some do).
In this specific sheet I'm using as a test, that means over 1200 calls to the API, which makes the whole process way too slow.
I can't seem to get row.indent to work though, I get error 1062, only parent id works.

Comment: Tracking in https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/issues/94

Comment: Accepted your answer as indeed, you can't do it all from a single call. I ended up implementing your solution 2. It's doing a few hundred calls to smartsheet but it's better than what we had earlier that had no bulk requests at all.