# Import XLS/Rows Copy: How to display contact name in a Contact Column?

Tags: python-2.7, smartsheet-api

Seeing release 1.3.3 of the smartsheet SDK and the ability to import XLS files straight from the SDK (which I haven't tried yet), I started thinking about how I would be able to achieve my goal to upload very large sheets with a minimum number of requests. 
(see related questions: [Building whole sheet programmatically with Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416108/building-whole-sheet-programmatically-with-python-sdk), [How to create a project sheet via the python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662143/how-to-create-a-project-sheet-via-the-python-sdk))

My current test methodology is to import an XLS file (though the UI so far), which comes in not formatted properly (Trying to make a project sheet, with gantt view, and resource management).

Using the python SDK, I use the `Sheets.copy_rows()` method to copy the rows from the sheet that was imported in the UI, to another blank sheet that is created following my project sheet template.

This seems to work perfectly, with the exception of the contact column, in which I would like to display the contact name rather than the contact email address.

According to https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#contact-list-columns:

> When creating or updating cells for a contact list column, the
>   displayValue attribute works as follows:
>
> - If displayValue is non-null and non-empty, the Smartsheet cell displays the value provided.
> - If displayValue is an empty string, the Smartsheet cell displays the email address.
> - If displayValue is null or absent, Smartsheet makes a best guess effort at filling it in with a contact’s name based on the email
>     address.

Looking at the sheet I created from the import, I can see my cell data as: `{"columnId": 7027801426552708, "value": "eleroy@******.com"}`.

According to the doc above, since displayValue is absent, I was hoping the copy into a contact list column would attempt to fill with the contact's name based on the email address.

**Is there a way I can force it to convert to the contact's name either on XLS import or during the copy?**

Edit:

As seen with some of the answers below, I guess it makes sense that the copy would copy the data as is, so I'm left trying to have it fill in the contact name on XLS import.

I am trying to find a way to inject both the display value and the value in Excel, but haven't succeeded yet. I have tried Hyperlinks, email links, =HYPERLINK() formula, but so far no success.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `Value` with the email address and the `displayValue` as the contact name, you should be able to get what you're looking for. For example, the following body of a generic HTTP request would display "MyUser Gmail" in the cell, but have the `myuser@gmail` as the contact email.

```
[
  {
   "toBottom": true, 
   "cells": [
      {
       "columnId": 6xxxxxxxxxxxxxx8, 
       "value": "myuser@gmail.com", 
       "displayValue": "MyUser Gmail"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think this applies in this case, as there is no request involved, all the values come from an XLS file, which doesn't (as far as I know) support a split between displayValue and value.

Comment: This might not have helped OP, but it solved my problem of updating contact cells via the API, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the `displayValue` is empty, it's an indication that this cell's Contact does not have a name associated with it. If your original sheet does include a name, the point of failure is likely in the copy process.

Without looking into the Python SDK, I might guess that `copy_rows()` is only copying by `value` and not `displayValue`. Try manually setting the value/displayValue of the contact cell and see if that works.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer.
When importing the XLS file, the excel file itself only contains email addresses. Smartsheet recognizes the contact, however it still uses the email as displayValue. (Actually it doesn't fill in the display value at all).  The copy itself copies that exactly, without filling in the display values either (which in retrospect I think is a good behavior to have). It sounds like the import itself is the part that doesn't follow the same behavior as highlighted in the documentation. If I enter names in the XLS sheet, then it doesn't recognize the contacts at all.

Comment: Smartsheet Contact cells contain more information than what would be stored in an Excel cell. However, since you can technically have multiple names associated with the same email, it's not as simple as importing an email and having it auto-associate with a name. You would still need to manually set the name afterwards.

Comment: Right, this is where I was at, but hoping there would be a better way. Sadly due to the limitation that using update_rows all the rows in the request must have the same parent, that means I'd need a few hundred requests per sheet, which totally cancels the point of uploading the whole XLS file at once. I'll check with the stakeholders of this project if they can accept an email address in there rather than a name.